# Help with nested selects used to select unlike items

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Ok so here is my problem....

I have one table that describes a bunch of buckets, which are all grouped by color.

Each of these buckets have a related table that holds an inventory of all of the items that are in those buckets.

I need to make a stored procedure that will be passed in the bucket color, and expect to get a bucket number back that is within that same color group but does not have any of the matching items of active buckets of that same color.

```
Bucket 

+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| BucketNum | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Group     | varchar(6) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Full      | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Active    | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


Bucket_Items
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Bucket_BucketNum | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Bucket_Group     | varchar(6) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ItemNum          | varchar(6) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Qty              | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+







Bucket
(SELECT *)
+-----------+-------+------+--------+
| BucketNum | Group | Full | Active |
+-----------+-------+------+--------+
|         7 | BLUE  |    0 |      1 |
|         8 | BLUE  |    0 |      0 |
|        12 | GREEN |    0 |      1 |
|        33 | GREEN |    0 |      0 |
|        56 | RED   |    0 |      0 |
|        99 | GREEN |    0 |      0 |
+-----------+-------+------+--------+


Bucket_Items
(SELECT *)
+------------------+--------------+---------+------+
| Bucket_BucketNum | Bucket_Group | ItemNum | Qty  |
+------------------+--------------+---------+------+
|                8 | BLUE         | AA11    |    1 |
|               12 | GREEN        | AA11    |   56 |
|               99 | GREEN        | AA11    |    7 |
|               12 | GREEN        | BB22    |    5 |
|                8 | BLUE         | CC33    |    3 |
|               12 | GREEN        | CC33    |    1 |
|               99 | GREEN        | DD44    |   88 |
|                7 | BLUE         | FF55    |   10 |
|               33 | GREEN        | FF55    |   56 |
|               33 | GREEN        | HH88    |   12 |
|               33 | GREEN        | JJ99    |   50 |
+------------------+--------------+---------+------+
```

so if I were to pass into the procedure 'GREEN'.

I want it to see that currently green has bucket 12 active in it's group, bucket 12 holds items AA11, BB22, & CC33 I would like the procedure to return 33.

33 passes because it is in green and has no shared items with bucket 12.  Bucket 99 fails, because it shares the item AA11 with bucket 12 and therefore cannot be picked.

Sorry if this is a little confusing and I would be more than willing to help explain it more, I am really struggling and I am hoping that the community can help me here.

Thanks to you all in advance.

EDIT:

Sorry this is what I have so far, I just get a little lost with all of the nested selects:

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE example (IN group_color INT)
BEGIN 

SELECT * FROM SELECT DISTINCT bucket, itemnum FROM bucket_items i, bucket b  
WHERE b.group = group_color AND b.bucketnum = i.bucket_bucketnum) AS x 
WHERE itemnum != (SELECT item FROM bucket WHERE active = true AND Group=group_color) AS y;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Did not mean to come off as the "have the internet do the work for me" type

Comment: Post your first attempts, let the crowd help you debug them - 'send me teh codez' isn't what we're here for.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add my broke code.  

    DELIMITER //   
    CREATE PROCEDURE example (IN group_color INT)  
    BEGIN   
  
    SELECT * FROM SELECT DISTINCT bucket, itemnum FROM bucket_items i, bucket b    
    WHERE b.group = group_color AND b.bucketnum = i.bucket_bucketnum) AS x   
    WHERE itemnum != (SELECT item FROM bucket WHERE active = true AND Group=group_color) AS y;  
  
    END //   
    DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the code for you, but here's the idea: *select* buckets where the *intersection* of the items in the bucket and items in buckets of the given color *is empty*.

Keywords: select, where, not exists, intersect...

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in that direction.  I hadn't thought of looking for an empty intersection!

Comment: understood, but so far better then any approach that I have come up with on my own.  Many thanks

Comment: So far your suggestion has helped me make progress, I have made two join statements that show me the items listed in active buckets and one that shows the items in inactive buckets.  
  
   I am however unable to seem to find a way to make those intersect.  


  
  
    SELECT BucketNum, ItemNum From Bucket  
    JOIN Bucket_Items  
    ON Bucket.BucketNum = Bucket_Items.Bucket_BucketNum   
    WHERE Bucket.Group='GREEN' AND Bucket.Active = TRUE;  
  
  
  Any other help would be appreciated!

Comment: Intersect is a keyword - like union and except - which takes two union-compatible relations and yields a new relation. If intersect isn't available in your flavor of SQL, other formulations are possible. A subquery with intersection should be fairly standard SQL, though.

Comment: hmmm I am using MySQL 5.5 ...  I will look around for other ways of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use MySQL I use MSSQL. I have always found it helpful to create views that filter items they way I want them and do all the heavy work. Then I write queries using those views.